# I'm getting this error too much and I couldnt fixt it even with following naming convention with capital letter

Tags: c#

here Collision starts with capital letter and i get this error

> Assets\scripts\Player.cs(49,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace
> name 'Collision' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It sounds like this is just a typo.  If it's not a class you wrote then it *most likely* follows C# naming conventions and begins with a capital letter, just like all of the other class names you're using.  If it *is* a class you wrote, where do you define it?

Comment: Hi please post code not a screenshot of it. Also in which line occours ?

Answer (score 3):

C# is case-sensitive. So you should type [Collision collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) instead of 'collision collision'. Similarly, the functions names should be **OnCollisionEnter** and **OnCollisionExit**.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)